# How can I get the machine information in HP-UX NILA B.11.23

Tags: hp-ux

I am using the HP-UX NILA B.11.23 and I would like to know the command which will give below details:

1. CPU information(number of CPUs,speed of cpus,version of cpus etc.,).
2. Memory information(main memory size and hard disk size).

Answer (score 1):

See the link below for a table of equivalent system administration commands in various Unix systems (incuding HP-UX):

http://www.unixguide.net/unixguide.shtml

You can use `top` to get memory information, `bdf` to get disk usage information. For CPU information have a look at this:

http://forums13.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447627+1296737258867+28353475&threadId=558731

Answer (score 1):

1. machinfo -v
2. print_manifest|grep Memory
   bdf
   ioscan -funNC disk
   diskinfo /dev/rdsk/